# Can't attach image with Paperclip via Amazon S3

Tags: file-upload, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm having a hard time trying to make Paperclip uploads to Amazon S3 via the `fog` gem. You see, I'm using Heroku so that's the way to go.

The problem is: I configured the app to send the uploads to my Amazon S3 bucket, the images are being sent and all but the object is saved with the `picture` attribute set to `/pictures/original/missing.png` and I don't know why.

Here is some data to help mitigate the problem:

I have a `Work` model, where I define a paperclip attachment for images called 'picture':

```
has_attached_file :picture, path: "app/public/system/images/:class/:id/:attachment/:style/img.:extension", styles: { large: "500x500>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
```

and I have created this particular initializer file called `paperclip_defaults.rb` for telling Rails that in fact, I want the uploads to go to Amazon S3 (actual keys hidden):

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  path: "app/public/system/images/:class/:id/:attachment/:style/img.:extension",
  storage: :fog,
  fog_credentials: {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: 'lovelovelove',
    aws_secret_access_key: 'dr_strangelove',
    region: 'sa-east-1'
  },
  fog_directory: 'florencioassets',
  fog_public: true,
  fog_host: "http://florencioassets.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
})
```

And my form is got the `multipart` attribute set to true and all.

There goes a sample file, which was uploaded, but not properly associated to the `Work` object I guess: https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/florencioassets/app/public/system/images/works/8/pictures/original/img.JPG

So, any idea on why the object is being saved without the actual picture? Guess it's not an uploading problem, per say.

Thank you for your time!

UPDATE:

I really wish someone can help me solve this the elegant way, but anyway, I made a quick workaround for this, if anyone is interested:

```
%w(original large medium thumb).each do |meth|
  define_method("#{meth}_picture_url") do
    "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/florencioassets/app/public/system/images/works/#{self.id}/pictures/#{meth}/img.JPG"  
  end
end
```